# Why can't wrap individual lines with abbreviational tag in my emmet-vim?

Tags: html, vim, emmet

I have installed vim and emmet plugin.
To create the following html structure

```html
 <ul>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>News</li>
     <li>Products</li>
     <li>Contacts</li>
    </ul>
```

with four lines text

```
About
News
Products
Contacts
```

Do as https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/  say.
1. to select four lines

[image]

2.to enter <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>
Nothing happend!

Where to input the abbreviation `ul>li*` to create target html structure?
How to wrap the four lines with `ul>li*` tag in my emmet-vim
Why no logo such as Tag: at the left bottom of vim window in my vim? How to set it in my vim?

[image]

[image]

In sublime text 3 we can achieve it this way.
1.to select all the four lines.
[image]
2.to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>
a narrow window  pop up at the bottom
[image]

3.to erase the red div tag  with backspace key,and input `ul>li*`

[image]

Done!

How to do in pure vim environment  with emmet plugin ?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking.

Comment: see https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.to press V into visul mode of vim

2.press V to select all the lines

[image]

3.to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>

[image]

Now the **tag:** logo display

4. to input  ul>li*

[image]

[image]

Done!